# How to get text from custom macOS text share extension?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, share-extension

SO, I'm making a macOS app which has a share extension accepting text. I have the same app made on iOS, where this code

```
func fetchAndSetContentFromContext() {
    guard let extensionItems = extensionContext?.inputItems as? [NSExtensionItem] else {
        return
    }
    for extensionItem in extensionItems {
        if let itemProviders = extensionItem.attachments as? [NSItemProvider] {
            for itemProvider in itemProviders {
                if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeText as String) {
                    itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeText as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { text, error in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.titleField.text = (text as! String)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

returns the text selected by the user, but for some reason it doesn't work on the Mac. What should I do?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same issue. Code works fine on iOS, but if I use the extension in a Mac catalyst app there is no text. 

[1] (null) "NSExtensionItemAttachmentsKey" : 0 elements 

But `[0] (null) "NSExtensionItemAttributedContentTextKey" : 678 bytes` changes size depending on text selected.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue with my Mac Catalyst app, and realised that the shared text was instead contained within `NSExtensionItem.attributedContentText`.

When my Share Extension retrieves `NSExtensionItem` details, if there aren't any `NSItemProvider`'s present I then check the above variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why this code wouldn't work on the macOS so the problem is out of this code, I think there are two possible cases on why it may happen:

1. your info.plist is not the same
2. the source application on the macOS doesn't send the content the same way that the source application on iOS does.

Comment: Could you detail the second option because the info.plist are the same?

Comment: @AppleLeaker you are receiving the content from another app. It can send you anything it wants through its code, it has nothing to do on what you select on the screen.